# How to access variable within object

Tags: javascript

Within the Chrome dev tools, I have access to the following variable:

```
myLayer
  e {options: Object, _layers: Object, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _leaflet_id: 29…}
    _geojson: Object
    _initHooksCalled: true
    _layers: Object
    30: e
        _icon: img.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-zoom-animated.leaflet-clickable
        _initHooksCalled: true
        _latlng: s.LatLng
        _leaflet_events: Object
        _leaflet_id: 30
        _map: e
        _popup: e
        _animated: true
        _content: "Location:Rotary Club of Dartmouth"
        _initHooksCalled: true
        _isOpen: false
        _source: e
        options: Object
        __proto__: i
        _popupHandlersAdded: true
        _shadow: null
        _zIndex: 267
        dragging: e
        feature: Object
        options: Object
        __proto__: i
    34: e
    __proto__: Object
    _leaflet_events: Object
    _leaflet_id: 29
    _map: e
    options: Object
    __proto__: i
```

I'm confused as it doesn't look like a normal object. I want to set the `isOpen` variable to `true` - how can I do this?

Comment: maybe try: `e['30']['_isOpen']= true`

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '30' of undefined`

Comment: `myLayer['e']['30']['_isOpen']`  You should be able to use the chrome console to see/validate this quite easily.